# PDO MySQL connection troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm running the following very basic PDO:MySql connection:

```
<?php

  $host = '127.0.0.1:8888';
  $db = 'communities';
  $user = 'root';
  $pass = 'yY5MF)q/DCzc';
  // Create connection
  try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysqli:host=$host;dbname=$db', $user, $pass);
  foreach($conn->query('SELECT * from city_detail') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
  }
  $conn = null;
  // Check connection
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
  echo "Connected successfully";
  ?>
```

I've modified php.ini to allow for `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` with no effect. Is there something else that I'm missing. I am using PHP7.0.3. The error message output is `Error!: could not find driver` Kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes to get variable data inside string:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysqli:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
```

Comment: that should not effect anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using `msqli` instead of `mysql`.